# How to move an image using the Graphics lib in OCaml?

Tags: graphics, ocaml

I'm programming in OCaml, and I use the Graphics library for the visualisation and Camlimages.

I have a moving element in the game, I would like to attach an image to it, the element have an `x` and `y` coordinates.

In the game loop, I have a function called `display` which displays on the screen the different elements of the game.

What I've done so far is including this in the `display` function of the element :

`Graphic_image.draw_image image (t_x (x_ pos -. 20.)) (t_y (y_ pos -. 7.))`

However my problem here is that the image is being duplicated at each frame.

My goal is to be able to avoid the duplication of the image at each frame or be able to move it.

How could I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to redraw what's supposed to be behind where the image you want to move no longer will be, so that will depend on your background. Quite often, it is easier to redraw the whole screen.

Comment: By redrawing the whole screen you mean calling ```clear_graph``` ? It is already called at the beginning of the main display function, calling it in the display_element would result in having only the element displayed on the screen sadly. I've thought of creating a type, but we can change the coordinates of an image ...

Answer (score 0):

Putting `clear_graph` at the beginning of your main render function should be sufficient. Can you provide a more complete outline of what's going on in that?